# how to have steps of actions in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

This is the pseudocode I hope to realize in p5.js:

The shape keeps rotating throughout the process.

The shape moves to point A.

The shape stay  at point A rotating for 2 seconds.

The shape moves to point B.

The shape stay  at point B rotating for 2 seconds.

The shape moves to point C.

The shape stay  at point C rotating for 2 seconds.

This is what I have already attempted which didn't work:

```javascript
var angle=0.0
var x=[20,40,60,320]
var y=[50,70,90,280]

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
    background(220);
}


function draw() {
  for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {

  translate(x[i], y[i]);

  setTimeout(rotate(angle), 1000);
  ellipse(0,0,10,100);
  angle+=0.1
    pop()}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really use the `setTimeout()` function for logic like this.

Instead, use the timing mechanisms built into P5.js, such as the `frameCount` variable, the `millis()` function, and the `lerp()` function.

Here's a simple example that moves a circle after 2 seconds:

```
var y = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  ellipse(width/2, y, 20, 20);

  if(millis() > 2000){
    y++;
  }
}
```

Comment: @santoku My code used an `if` statement. Your code uses a `while` loop. Your code is not going to show the movement between frames. But if you have follow-up questions, please post them in new questions instead of editing this one.

Comment: my bad. I was intending to append the new code but now I reverted to original question and new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363581/how-to-interpolate-between-two-consecutive-points-with-a-smooth-curve-in-p5-js thanks