# how to interpolate between two consecutive points with a smooth curve in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I intend to have an ellipse move smoothly between the stop points while keep rotating. It'll rotate for 1sec at point (20,50), transition to (40,70) on a smooth curve (bezier or random polynomial) and rotate till 3sec and move on to (160,190)

The current issue is that it jumps between stop points rather than move smoothly.

```javascript
var angle=0;
var x=[20,40,160] // x coordinates for stop points
var y=[50,70,190] // y coordinates for stop points
var t=[1000,2000,4000] // time for stop points
var i=0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
    background(220);
    frameRate(30);
    translate(x[i],y[i]);
    rotate(angle);


  if (millis() >= t[i] & millis() < t[i+1]){
    i+=1
  }

  fill(0);
  ellipse(0,0, 20, 80);
    angle++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to do this, and which approach you take depends on exactly how you want your code to behave.

Similar to the answer to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53358070/873165), you need to show the **movement** between the points.

Right now you're moving directly from one point to another. You need to show the intermediate steps.

Here are a few things to look into:

- The `frameCount` variable holds the current frame number. This is useful for exact timing of behaviors that you want to trigger on specific frames.
- The `millis()` function returns the number of milliseconds the sketch has been running. This is useful for duration-based logic, where you want to do something after a certain number of seconds.
- The `lerp()` function allows you to calculate values that change over time.
- You could also use delta values, where you move the X and Y values by some amount each frame.

Here's an example of that last approach:

```
var circleX = 20;
var circleY = 20;
var mode = 'move right';

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
    background(200);
    ellipse(circleX, circleY, 20, 20);

    if (mode == 'move right') {
        circleX++;
        if (dist(circleX, circleY, 380, 20) < 1) {
            mode = 'move down';
        }
    } else if (mode == 'move down') {
        circleY++;
        if (dist(circleX, circleY, 380, 380) < 1) {
            mode = 'move left';
        }
    } else if (mode == 'move left') {
        circleX--;
        if (dist(circleX, circleY, 20, 380) < 1) {
            mode = 'move up';
        }
    } else if (mode == 'move up') {
        circleY--;
        if (dist(circleX, circleY, 20, 20) < 1) {
            mode = 'move right';
        }
    }
}
```

But please note that this code is just an example, and there's a ton of room for improvement here. The important thing is that you need to move the scene a little bit each frame, instead of going directly from one point to another.